# C# Using ArrayList.IndexOf with multiple identical items

Tags: c#, arraylist

I've got a situation where I'm using an ArrayList to store a list of file names (full file path). When I add multiple items of the same file to the array, then use ArrayList.IndexOf to find the index (I'm reporting progress to a BackgroundWorker), it always returns the index of the first item since it's searching by the file name. This causes a problem with a progress bar, i.e. I'm processing 3 files, and when complete, the bar is only 1/3 full.

Here's some sample code (I'm simply adding items here, but in the real code they are added from a ListBox):

```
ArrayList list = new ArrayList();

list.Add("C:\Test\TestFile1.txt");
list.Add("C:\Test\TestFile1.txt");
list.Add("C:\Test\TestFile1.txt");

var files = list;
foreach (string file in files)
    backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(files.IndexOf(file) + 1);
```

When this runs, only 1 "percent" of progress is reported, since the IndexOf is finding the same file every time. Is there any way around this? Or does anyone have a suggestion on another way to get the index (or any unique identifier for each item)?

Comment: As an aside, is there a reason you're using `ArrayList` instead of `List<string>`? The non-generic collections should generally be avoided. They're in there for backward compatibility, but code written in the last 10 years would be better off not using them.

Comment: Why do you have the file in the same list multiple times anyway? Does it require multiple or single time processing or not?

Comment: you could use a `for` loop and use the increasing variable instead of `IndexOf`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The simplest approach is just to use the index to iterate:

```
for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
{
    backgroundWorks.ReportProgress(i + 1);
    // Do stuff with list[i]
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I don't know why I wasn't thinking of that. I think I had originally used an ArrayList because I was using an old library that required it (probably an older version of .NET). I converted my code to use List<string> instead, works like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

To achieve what you want, I would recomment using a `for` list. You won't have to search for any indexes and can report the progress easily to the `backgroundWorker1`:

```
for (int counter = 0; counter < files.Count; counter++)
{
    backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(counter + 1);
}
```

By doing this, you don't get problems with same filenames.

This would be the equivalent with `foreach`:

```
int counter = 1;
foreach (string file in files)
{
    backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(counter);
    counter++;
}
```

But I think it's better to use `for` in this case.

Answer (score 0):

You could make a copy of your list, and then remove each item from it as it is processed. Then you could return the percentage complete as a function of the count of the temp list divided by the count of the original list.

You could also just add to an int every time your background workers process a file and use that int to track the progress (percent complete should be the int divided by the number of files).

Of course with either approach you need to make sure you are modifying the variables in question in a thread-safe manner.

Answer (score 0):

Try this and it works fine for me in case of reading files having so many lines of data.

```
  int percentage = (int)((count / (double)lineCount) * 100.0);
  backgroundWorker5.ReportProgress(percentage);
```

Here count is total count  and linecount is present running count. By using thedse two,calculate the percentage. Keep this code in your for loop or while loop.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that progressbar max value is 100, and with one file processed out of three it should show 33(%) progress, you could count progress for each file processed and recalculate overall progress :

```
// list contains x file paths
var files = list;  

double progressStep = 1 / files.Count;

for(int i = 0; i < files.Count; i++)
{
    backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress((i + 1) * progressStep);
    ...
}
```

All that remained is to assign progress value in background worker to progress bar.